# even when i delete the elastic search folder why does localhost:9200 still gives same output?

Tags: elasticsearch

curl localhost:9200

This command still gives the same output as before. Why is there no impact of deleting the complete elastic search folder?

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~$ curl 'localhost:9200'
{
  "name" : "Postmortem",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.3.2",
    "build_hash" : "b9e4a6acad4008027e4038f6abed7f7dba346f94",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-04-21T16:03:47Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
hadoop@ubuntu:~$
```

---

**As suggested , Here's the output of command "ps aux | grep elastic"**

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~$ ps aux | grep elastic
hadoop    9513  0.4  7.2 1247056 139684 ?      Sl   09:13   1:29 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/home/hadoop/elasticsearch-2.3.2 -cp /home/hadoop/elasticsearch-2.3.2/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.2.jar:/home/hadoop/elasticsearch-2.3.2/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start
hadoop    9628  0.3  5.7 1244436 111284 ?      Sl   09:15   1:06 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Des.path.home=/home/hadoop/elasticsearch-2.3.2 -cp /home/hadoop/elasticsearch-2.3.2/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.2.jar:/home/hadoop/elasticsearch-2.3.2/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start --cluster.name my_cluster_name --node.name my_node_name
hadoop   12534  0.0  0.1   4692  2032 pts/27   S+   14:33   0:00 grep --color=auto elastic
hadoop@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Is your proccess running? `ps aux | grep elastic`

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 instances of Elasticsearch processes. Just deleting files does not stop them. Required files already loaded to memory. You can encounter errors when a file that is not loaded to memory is needed on run time. That can cause malfunctioning but wont stop the ES processes.

If you want to stop processes just kill them with kill command:

```
kill <process_id>
kill 9513 9628
```